# How to move the first tab of Terminal to the end using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

Given a Terminal window with multiple tabs, how can I move the first tab to the end?

I have tried with this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
  tell front window
    set current tab to first tab
    move tab 1 to after tab 2
  end tell
end tell
```

But it fails in the `set current tab` line with this error:

```
script error: A class name can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, I'm not sure Terminal understands how to handle it.

Try this, swapping Terminal to Safari. Works on Safari, errors on terminal, even if you specify a tab number… as it doesn't seem to grok 'current tab' either

As a test, this works for Safari

```
    tell application "Safari"
        tell front window
            set myTab to current tab
            move myTab to after last tab
        end tell
    end tell
```

Swapping this for Terminal, even if you remove the `current tab` error & run this

```
    tell application "Terminal"
        tell front window
            set myTab to tab 1
            move myTab to after last tab
        end tell
    end tell
```

It will still give error -10000 which is essentially "I don't understand this function"

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: execution error: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)

Comment: yup - error -10000 is essentially "I don't understand this function" On Safari it works, proving there's nothing wrong with the script itself, but Terminal just doesn't know what it means.

Comment: Thanks. Could you edit your answer telling that it's not possible, so I can accept it, please?